# How to add/create JAX-WS run time WebSphere Application Server V 7.0.37

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, ibm-was, ibm-rad-7.5

I want to create a jax-ws web service using IBM Rational developer for i (Version: 7.5.0) WebSphere Application Server V7.0.37. But when I right click wsdl file and click generate skeleton I can only see JAX-RPC runtime not JAX-WS. How to enable the JAX-WS in WAS7.

Please help I completely stuck with it.

Update:
I found that JAX-WS  provided by default with the WAS 7 and later versions, But I can't see it while generating web service. is this issue with RAD? Please see below link.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/jaxws/tjaxwsserv.htm

Thanks,
Naren

Comment: Hi,
 Down voter could please let me know anything wrong with question or need more information to understand the issue. So I can provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below link I found that in Rational developer for i doesn't contain the jax-ws support. RAD and RSA includes it. thought of sharing it may help somebody.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21405587

Thanks,
Naren

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've created a WS server and pick that server in your project facet runtime.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/jaxws/tjaxwsproj.htm?lang=en